# Google Cloud Platform Security Command Center - vague error when clicking finish on setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just went through the "wizard" to set up the security command center in my GCP application and as soon as I click "Finish" I get an error that says "Something went wrong and that's all we know" with a request id (see screenshot).

I have tried logging out and back in and tried 2 different browsers all with the same result.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this and know how I can get it working?  Google isn't turning up any answers for me.

Comment: Check if there are more details in Cloud Logging for SCC.

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Then repeat your steps. Sometimes there is useful information logged to the console.

Comment: @JohnHanley no errors logged in the browser console.  I'm looking for the cloud logging for security command center and can't find it.  Is it an API I need to enable first?

Comment: Since SCC fails to setup, the log entries are probably in another log section. Start with the `Admin Activity audit` logs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was able to get back to this this morning and dug into the logs and found a log message that says "Invalid Billing Tier".   All of the services I selected were not part of the "premium" suite.  Is there somethine else I need to do to set up a billing tier to make this work?

Comment: The error "Invalid Billing Tier" is important. Double-check which billing account is attached to the project. I recommend opening a Google Cloud Billing Support ticket. They will be able to tell you what is wrong. Billing support is free. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing